# get count of second td for each tr in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Excuse me (I cant write good English!), i want to get sum of count product for each category and append to category column.
how i can get sum of count of product for each tr and append to current tr in this CODE?

```js
$(function() {
  function groupTable($rows, startIndex, total) {
    if (total === 0) {
      return;
    }
    var i, currentIndex = startIndex,
      count = 1,
      lst = [];
    var tds = $rows.find('td:eq(' + currentIndex + ')');
    var ctrl = $(tds[0]);
    lst.push($rows[0]);
    for (i = 1; i <= tds.length; i++) {
      if (ctrl.text() == $(tds[i]).text()) {
        count++;
        $(tds[i]).addClass('deleted');
        lst.push($rows[i]);
      } else {
        if (count > 1) {
          ctrl.attr('rowspan', count);
          groupTable($(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1)
        }
        count = 1;
        lst = [];
        ctrl = $(tds[i]);
        lst.push($rows[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  groupTable($('#myTable tr:has(td)'), 0, 3);
  $('#myTable .deleted').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Product</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-1</td>
    <td>Product-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-1</td>
    <td>Product-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-1</td>
    <td>Product-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-1</td>
    <td>Product-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-2</td>
    <td>Product-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-2</td>
    <td>Product-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-2</td>
    <td>Product-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-2</td>
    <td>Product-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-3</td>
    <td>Product-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-3</td>
    <td>Product-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-3</td>
    <td>Product-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-4</td>
    <td>Product-6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category-4</td>
    <td>Product-6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not good practise to 'Hardcode' this - better to use a database a read the values (you can then Use SQL). Using your code, I would suggest adding a `id` to the `td` you want to sum (<td id="row1"`, then use `javascript` to `sum` them up

Comment: this table create by CMS and i cant to set id's for td or tr's

Comment: which CMS are you using? also, see [this](http://www.udel.edu/CIS/474/pconrad/06S/topics/javascript/examples/tables/sumOfAColumn.html)

Comment: Also, did code snippet change? are you trying to count the number of rows, or a quantity of products? This seemingly easily explained answer has now been made very unclear in what you are asking?

Comment: i want display sum of row's in side of category, at last i want prepend td to category col and set total of index of product